# Securing a Docker Container

Tags: docker, security

Suppose I have a docker file which creates an image that may execute a possibly malicious python program.
The goal is to get the output of this program, but I don't want my host machine to become compromised. The
`Dockerfile` is as follows:

```
 FROM python3.7-alpine
 COPY possiblyMalicious.py .
 ENTRYPOINT ["python3","possiblyMalicious.py"]
```

So then I build an image from this docker file and run a respective container. My question is: Is there a way to configure my host system such that the effects of `possiblyMalicious.py` stays and dies within the container, and if so how?

Comment: The second answer to the linked question is important: if the code can take advantage of a kernel exploit, it can compromise the host, and Docker provides no protection here.  You can also imagine a possibly-malicious program that uses a lot of CPU time and occasionally a small amount of network I/O as a cryptocurrency miner; that's not directly harmful to you and can't really be distinguished from many other benign tasks, but it's still probably not something you want to run.

Comment: I can put cpu and memory limits, but my concern is that the user may get access to the host and do whatever it wants. I saw in the discussion mention of AppArmor and SELinux. I am running these containers on AWS EC2 instances. Is there a way to configure an EC2 instance to avoid these issues?